How to read graphs for a simulated EMI filter

Hello everyone, I'm in the process of designing an EMI filter for a charger that is meant to connect to a trucks 12 V output. I've based the design of the filter off of the MAX17703 evaluation kit (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max17703evkita.pdf). I'm expecting a lot of noise in the signal and so I've attached a differential mode noise generator (V3) and a common mode noise generator (V2) in the simulations
The problem
I've done the AC analysis to find the bode plot which shows me the frequency response, but now I need to confirm that the noises are indeed being filtered out and I'm not sure of my method or if what I'm doing is even correct (I'm taking the transient analysis of the circuit with matching impedances across the input and output)

To my understanding filter_out- is showing the common mode noise and the differential mode noise is being filtered out already and so filter_out+ is just repeating the common mode noise, this leads me to another problem which is: why do I have to take reference across the terminals to get the needed filtered signal?
And additionally FFT of the signal shows

with the same problem here.
Am I meant to be taking filter_out- as a reference anyway? Am I even plotting the correct graph for checking the filter? Any and all help would be greatly appreciated
